# In Tor Browser Bundle how can I manually use a proxy address without turning off Tor?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, browsers, tor-button

When I use Tor Browser, the Tor button next to the address bar says "Tor Disabled" whenever I try to manually configure a certain HTTP/HTTPS proxy IP address. Is there any possible way to use a certain proxy address without disabling Tor?

Please see the screenshots below.

If it says "Tor Disabled", does that mean that your computer is connected to the proxy server without going through Tor?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up the proxy for Tor itself, not for the browser.

And yes, "Tor Disabled" means you are not protected.

Comment: How is a "proxy for Tor itself" configured?

Comment: You need to set a proxy in Tor options, not in the browser.